# Saving currently opened mxd and changes using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

Here is what I have so far...

```
import arcpy

import arcpy.mapping as map

mxd = map.MapDocument()

mxd.save()
```

And yes I know that map.MapDocument requires an argument, but I want it to automatically select the currently open mxd, and overwrite it. If I can't get it to select the currently open mxd I can use:

```
> import arcpy
> 
> import arcpy.mapping as map
> 
> mxd = map.MapDocument(C:\GIS\Untitled.mxd)
> 
> mxd.save()
```

But I would still like it to overwrite the mxd with the changes I just made to it in arcmap. Think of it like the save button except scripted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your path should look like this, using arcpy.mapping.MapDocument and surround your path with double quotes and double up your back slash:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\GIS\\Untitled.mxd")
```

or

Use string literal:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"c:\Temp\MXDs")
```

or

Add double quotes and change out backslash to forward slash:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:/GIS/Untitled.mxd")
```

If you only have one map document open you can define current map as:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
```

Comment: Can you set: mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:/GIS/Untitled.mxd"); open the mxd in arcmap; make changes; and save via mxd.save() ?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you open the mxd file in arcmap and this file marked as open file and python can't overwrite the file. i think your error is

```
IOError: MapDocObject: Unable to save.  Check to make sure you have write access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the storage device to hold your document
```

for solve this problem use saveACopy method and save it in another file.

```
import arcpy;
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\xTemp\sample.mxd");
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
mxd.saveACopy(r"d:\xTemp\name.mxd");
mxd.save();
```

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "e:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "e:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy_mapping.py", line 801, in save
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.save(*gp_fixargs((), True)))
IOError: MapDocObject: Unable to save.  Check to make sure you have write access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the storage device to hold your document.

```
 mxd2=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\xTemp\name.mxd");
 mxd2.save(); // in here file save with no error
 del mxd2;
```